# Race condition when dereferencing pointers

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, atomic

We are working in a very simple memory pool and we found a very interesting bug that we've not been able to solve.

The idea of the algorithm is as follows: there is a stack of "available" memory chunks, so each chunk has a pointer to the next available chunk. To avoid having a secondary data structure, we decided to use this same memory chunk to store the pointer. Therefor, the next available chunk is obtained by dereferencing this chunk: void *nextChunk = *((void **)chunk)

The code is originally implemented with C++ atomics, but we could simplify it and reproduce the issues with C atomic intrinsics:

```
void *_topChunk;

void *getChunk()
{
    void *chunk;

    // Try to reserve a chunk (for these tests, it has been forced that _topChunk can never be null)
    do {
        chunk = _topChunk;
    } while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&_topChunk, chunk, *((void **)chunk)));

    return chunk;
}

void returnChunk(void *chunk)
{
    do {
        *((void **)chunk) = _topChunk;
    } while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&_topChunk, *((void **)chunk), chunk));
}
```

For the tests that we've been running to debug this issue, we generated several threads that do this:

```
while (1) {
    void *ptr = getChunk();
    *((void **)ptr) = (void *)~0ULL;
    returnChunk(ptr);
}
```

At some point in the execution, getChunk() segfaults because it is trying to dereference a 0xfff... pointer. But from what is written in returnChunk(), *((void **)chunk) should never be 0xfff..., it should be a valid pointer from the stack. Why is it not working?

We have also tried to use an intermediate void *, instead of the dereference directly, and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Do what you want to do without asking our permission.:)

Comment: *To avoid having a secondary data structure, we decided to use this same memory chunk to store the pointer. Therefor, the next available chunk is obtained by dereferencing this chunk: void *nextChunk = *((void **)chunk)*  That seems fundamentally broken.  How does that prevent two or more threads from simultaneously seeing the same old value and then simultaneously writing the same new value?

Comment: @AndrewHenle For the getChunk() function, the compare & swap guarantees that the chunk obtained is different for each thread that accesses simultaneously. For the returnChunk() function, the pointer to the next chunk is updated before "it is made public" (it is pushed to the stack). At least, that's what we think that should be happening in the posted code.

Comment: one simple way to avoid a race condition is to use a mutex.  Suggest: 1) lock the mutex 2) manipulate the pointers 3) unlock the mutex

Comment: @user3629249 We are trying to do this memory pool as fast and slim as possible. Therefor, it is better to use just two atomic operations than a full mutex. If we are not able to make it work with atomic operations, we will resort to mutexes.

Comment: You are trying to loop and wait for topChunk to become "free". Why not use a standard tried and true spin lock then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in function getChunk. The third parameter to __sync_bool_compare_and_swap might be outdated. Let's have a look on a slightly modified version of getChunk:

```
void *getChunk()
{
    void *chunk;
    void *chunkNext;

    // Try to reserve a chunk (for these tests, it has been forced that _topChunk can never be null)
    do {
        chunk = _topChunk;
        chunkNext = *(void **)chunk;
        //chunkNext might have been changed meanwhile, but chunk is the same!! 
    } while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&_topChunk, chunk, chunkNext));
    return chunk;
}
```

Lets assume we have a simple chain of three chunks, located at addresses 0x100, 0x200 and 0x300. And we need three threads (A, B & C) to break the chain:

```
//The Chain: TOP -> 0x100 -> 0x200 -> 0x300 -> NIL
 Thread   
 A      chnk     = top;         //is 0x100
 A      chnkNext = *chnk;       //is 0x200
   B       chnk = top           //is 0x100
   B       chnkNext = *chnk;    //is 0x200
   B       syncSwap();          //okay, swap takes place
   B       return chnk;         //is 0x100
   /*** The Chain Now: TOP -> 0x200 -> 0x300 -> NIL ***/
     C        chnk = top;      //is 0x200
     C        chnkNext = *chnk //is 0x300
     C        syncSwap         //okay, swap takes place
     C        return chnk;     //is 0x200
   /*** The Chain Now: TOP -> 0x300 -> NIL ***/
   B       returnChunk(0x100); 
   /*** The Chain Now: TOP -> 0x100 -> 0x300 -> NIL ***/
 A      syncSwap(&Top, 0x100, 0x200 /*WRONG, *chnk IS NOW 0x300!!!!*/  );
 A      return chnk;
```

Comment: @markmb No, `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval)`, returns true, because the pointer refers (again) to 0x100.

Comment: Yes, that is most likely the problem. I could not see this extreme case myself. Thank you very much. @user5329483: I deleted my comment because I saw my mistake in it, but I did not see your comment to it before deleting it, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution for your problem unless you use a real lock.